# Database security - one of two columns can't be null

Tags: sql, hibernate

I have the table elements_hi, is there any possibility to check if element1 or element 2 is not null? I mean I want to have filled always one of them and the database check if only one of them is not null.

```
CREATE TABLE public.elements_hi (
    id int8 NOT NULL,
    element1_id int8 NULL,
    element2_id int8 NULL,
    concentration int4 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT el_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT el_heal_idx_el1_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (element1_id) REFERENCES public.element1(id),
    CONSTRAINT el_heal_idx_el2_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (element2_id) REFERENCES public.element2(id),
);
```

Comment: `check (e1 is not null or e2 is not null)`? (Or do you mean exactly one of them must be null?)

Comment: For columns of compatible types you could use `check ( coalesce( c1, c2, c3, ... ) is not null )` to ensure that at least one value is not null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CHECK CONSTRAINT

```
ALTER TABLE public.elements_hi
ADD CONSTRAINT element1_element2   
   CHECK (element1_id IS NOT NULL OR element2_id IS NOT NULL);  
GO
```

Similarly, if you need one of the two to always be null.

```
ALTER TABLE public.elements_hi
ADD CONSTRAINT element1_element2   
   CHECK ((element1_id IS NOT NULL AND element2_id IS NULL) OR (element1_id IS NULL AND element2_id IS NOT NULL));  
GO
```